# Using a composite key from one table in a field in another table

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables. One table has First Name and Last Name fields (together they make a composite key for that table). The other table has an 'Author' field. I want the author field to be a lookup field that displays both the First AND Last names of each author from the Author table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings, and use this as Rowsource of a single-column combobox:

```
SELECT [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS FullName FROM tblPerson
```